# Apache POI - PIE Chart - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Category and values must have the same point count

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, apache-poi, pie-chart

I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Category and values must have the same point count. What am i missing here in the below code? Thanks.

```
XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
                            new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, 
                    new CellRangeAddress(1, 6, 0, 1));

            XDDFChartData chartData = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null,
                    null);
            chartData.setVaryColors(true);
            chartData.addSeries(cat, val);
            chart.plot(chartData);
```

[image]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Category and values must have the same point count.
at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData$Series.replaceData(XDDFChartData.java:170)
at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData$Series.(XDDFChartData.java:161)
at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFPieChartData$Series.(XDDFPieChartData.java:107)
at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFPieChartData.addSeries(XDDFPieChartData.java:97)

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear. See [CellRangeAddress](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html) for what the constructor parameters mean.

So your `cat` data source is from row 0 to row 0 and column 0 to column 1. That is `A1:B1`. But your `val` data source is form row 1 to row 6 and column 0 to column 1. That is `A2:B7`. So `cat` data source contains 2 cells but `val` data source contains 12 cells.

According to your screen shot of `Excel` sheet, it should be:

```
XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
                             new CellRangeAddress(1, 5, 0, 0));
XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, 
                                      new CellRangeAddress(1, 5, 1, 1));
```

That is `cat` data source `A2:A6` and `val` data source `B2:B6`.